# How to interface ma output with webpage by php?

Tags: webmathematica, raspberry-pi

Since Raspberry pi has a free version ma, I am wondering how to interface it with php on web.

I write some simple code as

```
<?php
$math="/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.0/Executables/math -batchinput -batchoutput";
    ?>
    <!DoCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Mathematica on Raspiberry pi</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="wrap">
          <h1>Mathematica on Raspiberry pi</h1>
          <h3>Input your expression</h3>
          <div id="stdin">
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
          <input name="stdin" />

          <input type="submit" value="Evaluate" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <h3>The Results</h3>
      <div id="stdout">
        <?php
        $cmd=$_POST['stdin'];
        echo $math($cmd);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the output can't work (although the $math command can interface in terminal).

Comment: `$math` is a string, how could this possibly work? Have a look at [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: thanks, but `echo exec($math.' '.$cmd);` still not work.

Comment: I also fonund the ma API maybe helpful: http://products.wolframalpha.com/docs/PHP_Binding_0_1.zip